# Display all comments for a WordPress blog on a single page?

Tags: wordpress

What I need - The code to perform the following:

I am trying to setup a WordPress template that will display all the comments that have been posted to my blog. How do I pull all comments and have all the same formatting that is applied to comments under a single post? Such as the formatting that occurs when comments are displayed using the comments.php template.

Note I want to pull all the comments from my blog to a single page. I still want the comment pagination but instead of having 20 comments under post #1, 20 under post #2, etc. I want to have all 40 show up at one time on one page.

Comment: In the editor section it should have a loop that displays the comments, change the number of times that loop iterates.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I guess I should have been more clear. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function.

```
<?php foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
<div><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

See also the [apply_filters()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) function to apply [comment output filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Comment.2C_Trackback.2C_and_Ping_Filters) to specific fields.

```
<?php echo apply_filters('comment_text', $comment->comment_content); ?>
```

**EDIT:**

For pagination, you can use the offset and number parameters of the get_comments() arguments:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'number'=>20,
        'offset'=>0,
        'status'=>'approve',
    );
    foreach (get_comments($args) as $comment) {
        // ...
    }
?>
```